Explicit bounds for Merten's Theorem
From Merten's theorem, it is known that
$$\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)={e^{-\gamma}\over\log x}\left\{1+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log x\right)\right\}$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant.
I want to know whether there are explicit bounds known regarding this result. In other words, do we know of $A$ and $B$ such that
$${e^{-\gamma}\over\log x}\left\{1+ {A\over\log x}\right\}\le \prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\le {e^{-\gamma}\over\log x}\left\{1+ {B\over\log x}\right\}$$
for all $x$?

See also this post.
